# How to Change ARKit Update Function Frequency (FPS)?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am currently working to limit the CPU load of my ARKit iOS application. In order to do that, I need to limit the amount of time per second the session(_ didUpdate: function is called per second. I tried changing the preferredFramesPerSecond property of my ARSCNView. That did slow down the fps of the incoming video feed, but the update function was still getting called an insane amount of times per second. My other solution was to use the timeStamp property of the incoming ARFrame and calculate the difference between the last saved render time. I am trying to run the program on Swift Playgrounds and for whatever reason the setting of a variable within the render loop with type TimeInterval fails. This solution does work on a normal iOS app. Is there any proper way to directly set the frequency of the update function for ARKit?

Current Code:

My AR Properties:

```
private lazy var lastRenderTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

private lazy var sceneView: ARSCNView = {
    let sceneView = ARSCNView()
    sceneView.session.delegate = self
    sceneView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30
    sceneView.debugOptions = [.showFeaturePoints]
    sceneView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return sceneView
}()
```

And the delegate implementation:

```
extension MainViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        let timeSinceLastUpdate = lastRenderTime - frame.timestamp

        if timeSinceLastUpdate >= 0.1 || timeSinceLastUpdate < 0 {
            lastRenderTime = frame.timestamp
            // Do Updating Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was facing the same issue and I found a decent workaround for this problem. You could set a timer variable and based on the timer then call whatever you need in the didUpdate function. I'll provide some code example below where I will call the session Didupdate frame function every 0.5 seconds. (You may alter it to fit whatever looks best)

Code example:

```
//setting up timer variables and functions 
    var time = 0.0
    var timer = Timer()

    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func resetTimer() {
        timer.invalidate()
        time = 0
        startTimer()
    }

    @objc func updateTime() {
        if time < 0.5 {
           time += 0.1
        } else {
            resetTimer()
        }
    }
```

In your viewdidload or viewwillappear call

```
startTimer()
```

Finally in your didUpdate function make a conditional statement

```
if time != 0.5 {
   return
} else {
   * your code * 
}
```

Comment: You should never rely on a timer to measure a time interval. Just get a start date object and check `timeIntervalSinceNow` or for a positive result on past dates  `Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)`

Comment: I consider @LeoDabus answer as a more straight and reliable option. Starting and reinitializing a timer can make your code hard to understand.
Since the detectionRequestHandler handler is THE main gate to proceed with any changes, one can simply distinguish e.g. observation/no observation in image detection and change the timespan accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to influence the frames per second of the session directly, but I came up with a solution that may work. ⤵︎

```swift
/// Keeps track of the number of frames that render in a session.
var frameCount: UInt64 = 0


/// This runs the update() function every other frame.
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    
    if frameCount % 2 == 0 {
        update()
    }

    frameCount += 1
}

// Place all of your scene logic in here.
func update() {
    ...
}
```

You can adjust the modulus value `2`, to get the desired framerate. For example, if the scene is running at 120 FPS then a modulus of `4` would run the `update()` function 30 times a second.